# 1D travelingsalesman with constraint

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I'm working on a algorithm for what seems like a very easy problem but I cannot find an efficient algorithm for it. The problem is as following: 
I have a list of numbers (0-50) and a start location and have to visit each of these while minimalising the total distance travelled. Some pairs of locations require me to visit the other one first (so to visit 29 I must first pick something up on 26). However I cannot quite seem to figure out how to do this without just generating every option. Any ideas?

For example we have the following

```
startLocation=25;
targetPairs=[[1,5],[7,12],[22,23]]
visitLocations=[4,6,8,2]
```

this means that we have to visit 1 before 5, 7 before 12 and 22 before 23. We also have to visit the location 4,6,8 and 2. 
One option to get started is to go too 1(distance 24) then go to 4 (distance 3 total 27) then go to 5 (distance 1 total 28) we can then go on to 6 (distance 1 total 29) or for the full set (7(30),8(31),12(35),22(45),23(46)).

Logically the limit for the number of locations we have to visit is 50 pairs and 50 locations.

Comment: Any idea for a better name and why the close vote?

Comment: Can you give some examples? And 1D means that all points is in Ox axis?

Comment: I added an example of what I mean.

Comment: So we have to visit all `targetPairs` plus `visitLocations`?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Any constraint about number of targetPairs and visitLocations?

Comment: At most there are 50 pairs and 50 locations.

Comment: What's the distance between `1` and `50` ?

Comment: That would be 49, the distances are always equal to the difference between the points.

Comment: In your example solution, you don't visit 22 before 23. The list of unconditionally visited locations can be ignored, because all locations lie between locations from the target pairs thatb you have to visit anyway.

Comment: I use ext. as the total answer would be rather long.

Comment: Starting with some easy cases: If startLocation - leftmostTarget <= rightmostTarget - startLocation *and all precedence constraints are from left-to-right*, it's optimal to move straight to the leftmost target and sweep right.  If startLocation - leftmostTarget >= rightmostTarget - startLocation *and all precedence constraints are from right to left*, it's optimal to move straight to the rightmost target and sweep left.

Answer (score 1):

The problem *can* be solved by the following potentially exponential-time algorithm, and if it's NP-hard (as I suspect) then you won't be able to do much better (where by "much", I mean find an algorithm with polynomial time complexity -- it may well be possible to reduce the base of the exponential-time algorithm).

Basically, do a best-first search in a state space in which each state consists of two things: a current position, and a *set* of already-visited locations.  (It's unfortunately *not* sufficient to simply track the number of already-visited cities.)  We always have at most the following 2 moves from each point in this state space:

1. Move left to the *nearest* visitable location
2. Move right to the *nearest* visitable location

That's because there is always an optimal solution in which each location is visited the first time we move to or past it after it has become visitable.  Here, "visitable" means that all a location's predecessors (including predecessors of predecessors, etc.) have already been visited.

Any state in which all locations have already been visited is a goal state.  Using best-first search (implementable with a priority queue, or in this case, simply a size-50 array would do), the first such state found will correspond to an optimal solution.  This algorithm will take time exponential in the number of locations that need to be visited.

This search can be sped up by using the A* algorithm -- that is, by using some admissible heuristics to determine a lower bound on the distance remaining from a given state.  It should be fairly easy to come up with something reasonable here -- e.g. let x be the leftmost unvisited location and y the rightmost, then if our current position z is between them, it will require at least min(2(z-x) + y-z, z-x + 2(y-z)) to visit both of them from z.  (If instead z is to the left or to the right of all unvisited cities, it will take at least y-z, or at least z-x, respectively.)  Taking predecessors into consideration could improve the bounds considerably.

Comment: Did you have a feel for how to prove that it was NP-hard?  I tried but didn't really get anywhere.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: Unfortunately I have no idea...  My "feeling" is based only on the (pretty shaky) notion that, since many restrictions of the TSP are NP-hard (e.g. to the Euclidean or rectilinear metric), this might be too.  :-(